# Get request working on Postman, but not in React.js?

Tags: javascript, axios, postman

My API GET request is working in Postman, but not in React.JS / the browser. I have to pass in a username and password at the beginning of the URL to gain access to the API information, which again works fine in Postman, but not React/browser.

My GET request looks like this:

```
http://username:password@mywebsite.com:4040/api/stuff/stuff2
```

It works in Postman, but when I do an axios GET request in React, in the console.logs it looks like the username:password portion of the request has been removed and I get an error code saying I'm unauthorized.

Here's the React code:

```
    getList = () => {
        axios
            .get('http://username:password@mywebsite.com:4040/api/stuff/stuff2')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({
                    list: res.data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Do you know how to make the GET request work in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use [basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) this works in Postman because Postman isn't doing an AJAX request, browsers simply do not let you pass that information in an AJAX request URL.

Previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44239543/490790)!

You can pass auth as an option to your `axios.get` call like this:

```js
axios.get(
  'http://mywebsite.com:4040/api/stuff/stuff2', 
   {
     auth: {
       username: 'username',
       password: 'password'
     }
   }
)
```