# axios Authorization username and password

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-cli

I have an api with the following documentation. I am currently using axios. I am getting an Unauthorized error

```js
const res=axios.get("http://aaaaaaaaa.com", {
                Authorization: {
                    'Username' : '09822222222',
                    'Password' : 'sana1234'
                },
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
```

Header
“Content-Type”: “application/json”
The login credentials should be passed as basic-auth through *Authorization* header
Username: “test”
Password: “test”

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send Basic Auth with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072750/how-to-send-basic-auth-with-axios)

Comment: You also might want to check out CORS, if you are trying to connect to another domain.