# API access denied in ReactApp, how to fetch data from API server

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I will ask again. Hope someone who has experienced the same issue offer me some help.
Background: to build a translation app from Swedish to English with ReactApp.
Issue: when access an open URL with `axios.get(`https://dictapi.lexicala.com/test`)`, I am able to get data, but if replace with `axios.get(`https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=${keyWord}`)`, resulted in `GET https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=asdf 401`

I suppose I need to find a way to embed my user credentials for api provider in my ReactApp code, everytime before use `axios.get(`https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=${keyWord}`)`, I should make a login act to this api server. Because, I can access api server with URL in chrome, e.g. `https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=es&text=azul` due to the fact chrome saved my user credentials.

Please indicate how to search the right question for sovling this problem? I am not expert with ReactJS and neither am I an English native speaker. What techniques should I refer to ?

Comment: there's a great resource https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-axios-with-react/

Comment: Thank you, but it does not show me how to POST my usrname and password to API server to initiate a session.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not related to React. It's related to a network call.
Looking at https://dictapi.lexicala.com looks like it requires a basic auth.
So probably what do you want to check is that question: [How to send Basic Auth with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072750/how-to-send-basic-auth-with-axios)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't signed up for the service so I cant analyse the API, but I imagine you're assigned an API key - you'll want to either send this via url parameters or headers, depending on how the api works. These are both pretty easy to do with axios basic auth.