# How to Update State when using onClick Function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a user profile from calling on axios, using reactjs. But I can only see an updated state when I have useEffect but nowhere else. In loginPage.js, I am trying to get the most updated states of entryfirstName, entryLastName, and role to post to the login function, which ties back into my userProvider.js. I am not sure how else to update the states so any feedback is better than what I got.

I am very new to react and I haven't been able to solve this so any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code for loginPage.js

```
export default function SignIn()  {
  const { login } = useContext(UserContext);

  const [email_input, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password_input, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [entryfirstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [entrylastName, setlastName] = useState('');
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');
  const [entryuser, setEntryUser] = useState({});

  const baseURL = 'http://samplesite.org/';

  const handleEmailInputChange = event => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };
  const handlePasswordInputChange = event => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const gatherData = async () => {
    try {
      const userlogins = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/user`);
      setEntryUser(userlogins.data.users);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  
  const updateData = (loggedin_id, userFirst, userLast) => {
    setRole(loggedin_id);
    setFirstName(userFirst);
    setlastName(userLast);
  }, [role, entryfirstName, entrylastName]);

  const submit = () => {
    if (email_input === null || password_input === null || email_input === "" || password_input === "") {
      alert("Enter username and password");
    } 
    else {
      if (entryuser.map(x => x.email === email_input && x.password === password_input)) {
          console.log("Email and Password exists");
          const loggedin = entryuser.filter(obj => obj.email === email_input); 
          const loggedin_role = loggedin.map(({ role }) => `${role}`);
          const loggedin_id = loggedin_role.toString();
          const userNames_1 = loggedin.map(({ firstName }) => `${firstName}`);
          const userNames_2 = loggedin.map(({ lastName }) => `${lastName}`);
          const userFirst = userNames_1.toString();
          const userLast = userNames_2.toString();
          updateData(loggedin_id, userFirst, userLast);
        }
      else {
        alert("User Does not Exist.");
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    gatherData(); 
    console.log('useEffect role: ', role);
    console.log('useEffect firstname: ', entryfirstName);
    console.log('useEffect lastname: ', entrylastName);
  }, [role, entryfirstName, entrylastName]);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    submit();
    console.log('role: ', role);
    console.log('firstname: ', entryfirstName);
    console.log('lastname: ', entrylastName);
    login(entryfirstName, entrylastName, email_input, password_input, role);
  }
```

Here is code for userProvider.js

```
import React from "react";
import UserContext from "./UserContext";

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState({ 
      firstName: '', 
      lastName: '', 
      email: '', 
      role: '', 
      auth: false 
    });
  
    const login = (firstName, lastName, email, password, role) => {
      setUser((user) => ({
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          role: role,
          auth: true,
        }));
      };
  
    const logout = () => {
      setUser((user) => ({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        role: '',
        auth: false,
      }));
    };
  
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider 
        value={{ 
          user, 
          login, 
          logout }}
      >
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  };

export default UserProvider;
```

Comment: Hy, can you give us a link to a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First, in your context

I would put the call to the axios:
note: Why call all users? I think this is not right, maybe `axios.get(`${baseURL}/user/${email}`);` for most specific user, best pratices security or for example:

```
const login = async (firstName, lastName, email, password, role) => {
      if(firstName && lastName && email && password && role){

      const { data } = await axios.post(session_url, {}, {
         auth: {
           email: email,
           password: password
        }
      });

      if(data){
        setUser((user) => ({
            firstName: data.user.firstName,
            lastName: data.user.lastName,
            email: data.user.email,
            role: data.user.role,
            auth: true,
        }));
      }
}
```

Please read: [Auth - Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072750/how-to-send-basic-auth-with-axios)

but let's continue

```js
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import UserContext from "./UserContext";

const baseURL = 'http://samplesite.org/';

const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [entryuser, setEntryUser] = useState({});
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ 
      firstName: '', 
      lastName: '', 
      email: '', 
      role: '', 
      auth: false 
    });

   // you need a useEffect to verify if user is logged
   useEffect(() => {
      const getCurrentUser = localStorage.getItem("currentUser");
      if (getCurrentUser) {
        const currentUser = JSON.parse(getCurrentUser);
        // now you need validate expireAt
        // also make an axios call here, to check if you are authenticated on the backend
        // validate all necessary
        setUser((user) => ({
                firstName: currentUser.firstName, 
                lastName: currentUser.lastName, 
                email: currentUser.email, 
                role: currentUser.role, 
                auth: true,
        }));
      }
    },[])
  
    const login = async (firstName, lastName, email, password, role) => {
       try {
         const userlogins = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/user`);

         if(userLogins.data) {
            setEntryUser(userlogins.data.users);
            const loggedin = entryuser.filter(obj => obj.email === email); 
            const loggedin_role = loggedin.map(({ role }) => `${role}`);
            const loggedin_id = loggedin_role.toString();
            const userNames_1 = loggedin.map(({ firstName }) => `${firstName}`);
            const userNames_2 = loggedin.map(({ lastName }) => `${lastName}`);
            const userFirst = userNames_1.toString();
            const userLast = userNames_2.toString();

          // you need save this data in cookies or localstorage, 
          // I use crypto-js in localStorage

            const currentUser = {
               firstName: userFirst,
               lastName: userLast,
               role: loggedin_id,
               expireAt:  // here you need a time to expire sesion
             }

            localStorage.setItem("currentUser",  JSON.stringify(currentUser));

            setUser((user) => ({
               firstName: userFirst,
               lastName: userLast,
               email: email,,
               role: loggedin_id,
               auth: true,
             }));
         };
       } 
       catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
       }
     };
  
    const logout = () => {
      setUser((user) => ({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        role: '',
        auth: false,
      }));
    };


  
    return (
      <UserContext.Provider 
        value={{ 
          user, 
          login, 
          logout }}
      >
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );
  };

export default UserProvider;
```

### Second in your component

Note: Why does your login ask for your name and surname and role? It is better to handle this data from the backend and you could use only email and password

```js
interface IFormLogin {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  role: string;
}

export default function SignIn()  {
  const { login } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [formLogin, setFormLogin] = useState<IFormLogin>({
     email: "";
     password: "";
     firstName: "";
     lastName: "";
     role: "";
  })

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    setFormLogin((formState: IFormLogin) => ({
      ...formState,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      },
    }));
  };

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {email, password, firstName, lastName, role} = formLogin;

    if (!email && !password && !firstName && !lastName && !role) {
      alert("Enter all data");
      return;
    }

    login(firstName, lastName, email, password, role);
  }

 return(
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <input name="email" type="email" value={formLogin.email || ""} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   <input name="password" value={formLogin.password || ""} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   <input name="firstName" value={formLogin.firstName || ""} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   <input name="lastName" value={formLogin.lastName || ""} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   <input name="role" value={formLogin.role || ""} onChange={handleInputChange} />
   <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
 );
```

### Now if you need user data in other component

```js
const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
console.log(user.firstName);
```

## Recommendations

Please DON'T SAVE the password anywhere in the client, I mean localstorage, session storage, cookies, context, redux, etc.

You can use [Json web token](https://jwt.io/) to encrypt data from the backend and that token save in localstorage.

[JWT Authentication in React](https://www.permify.co/post/jwt-authentication-in-react#:%7E:text=JWT%2C%20or%20JSON%20Web%20Token,protected%20data%20and%20access%20services.)

Note: I use TypeScript in any case, please omit that part if you want.